# Implementing an integer merge sort in C#

Tags: c#, mergesort

Recently got a bubble sort algorithm functioning, and decided I would try a merge sort algorithm, I'm trying to write it from scratch as a personal challenge, I feel as though my logic is fundamentally flawed in it however, Not knowing where else to turn for advice, I welcome any input. I feel like C# doesn't like my declaration of sub-arrays, they do seem to be an improper solution also

```
public static void MergeSort(int[] A) // WIP
    {
        if (A.Length % 2 == 0 )     //Checks if input array is even
        {
            int[] B;                //Declares sub array
            int[] C;                //Declares sub array
            for (int x = 0; x < A.Length ; x++)     //Performs an action for every item item in the array
            {
                if (x < A.Length / 2)               //selects the first half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array B
                {
                    B[x] = A[x];
                }
                if(x > A.Length / 2)                //Selects the second half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array C
                {
                    C[x] = A[x];

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: This kind of question would be a good fit for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring references to arrays, but never initializing them. `B` and `C` will be null and you'll get an exception if you try to do anything with them.

```
        //  Declares *reference* to sub array, and creates it as well.
        int[] B = new int[A.Length];

        //  Declares *reference* to sub array, and creates it as well.
        int[] C = new int[A.Length];
```

You could use `List<int>` instead of arrays.

The thing is, you'll only be using the first half of `B` and the second half of `C`. Is that what you want? If you want `B` to be *just* the first half of  `A`, and `C` to be *just* the last half of `A`, do this. You can use `List<int>` pretty much identically to an array, but you can `Add()` to it, and it has a `Count` property instead of a `Length` property:

```
        var B = new List<int>();
        var C = new List<int>();

        for (int x = 0; x < A.Length ; x++)     //Performs an action for every item item in the array
        {
            if (x < A.Length / 2)               //selects the first half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array B
            {
                B.Add(A[x]);
            }
            if(x > A.Length / 2)                //Selects the second half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array C
            {
                C.Add(A[x]);
            }
        }
```

Another thing: I'd put an `else` before the second `if` here, for clarity more than runtime efficiency.

But what happens if x is *equal* to `A.Length / 2`? If that case is handled in code you didn't include in your question, never mind.

```
            if (x < A.Length / 2)               //selects the first half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array B
            {
                B.Add(A[x]);
            }
            else if(x > A.Length / 2)                //Selects the second half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array C
            {
                C.Add(A[x]);
            }
```

You could, howerver, simplify that code as follows:

```
if (A.Length % 2 == 0)
{
    //  Take the first half and make an array out of that sequence
    var B = A.Take(A.Length / 2).ToArray();

    //  Skip the first half and make an array out of the remaining sequence
    var C = A.Skip(A.Length / 2).ToArray();
}
```

But if you're meant to be demonstrating a grasp of basic programming fundamentals rather than C# trivia, your loop method is best.

Comment: Your solution is very clever, I didn't realize such methods even existed. However I am going to stick to the Loop method

Comment: @Anyon As I said, I think that's wise. But you're going to need to initialize `B` and `C`, and I think it's very likely that you want them to be `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors because you are trying to use an unassigned variable (arrays B and C). If you need to understand how arrays work go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).
If you initialize `int[B] = new int[A.Length / 2];` then your code will compile without errors.

Your code should look like this, just in order to work, I did not refactor anything, just did the minimum to make it work:

```
 public static void MergeSort(int[] A) // WIP
        {
            if (A.Length % 2 == 0)     //Checks if input array is even
            {
                int[] B = new int[A.Length / 2];                //Declares sub array
                int[] C = new int[A.Length / 2];                //Declares sub array
                for (int x = 0; x < A.Length; x++)     //Performs an action for every item item in the array
                {
                    if (x < A.Length / 2)               //selects the first half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array B
                    {
                        B[x] = A[x];
                    }
                    if (x > A.Length / 2)                //Selects the second half of the input array and assigns it to sub-Array C
                    {
                        C[x] = A[x];

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now my main issue is how to know how many arrays I need to create such that all arrays get broken down into arrays of size one, (When original input is unknown) I feel as though this is not quite an optimal implementation